# using imagemagick in ruby to convert pdf to png

Tags: ruby, imagemagick

I am trying to convert a pdf to image following [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#write) stackoverflow post.

I have imagemagick installed on mac osx via brew:

```
$ brew ls --versions imagemagick
imagemagick 6.8.9-5
```

Now I attempt to do exactly what he did in the stackoverflow answer:

```
> require 'RMagick'
> Dir.chdir "/Users/donato/Downloads"
> Dir.pwd
=> "/Users/donato/Downloads" 
> Dir.entries(Dir.pwd).select {|f| f =~ /sample_template.pdf/}
 => ["sample_template.pdf"]
> pdf =  Magick::ImageList.new("sample_template.pdf")
=> []
  scene= 
> pdf.class
=> Magick::ImageList
2.1.2 :017 > pdf.write "sample_template.png"
  ArgumentError: no images in this image list
  from (irb):17:in `write'
  from (irb):17
  from /Users/donato/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

The documentation for the write method is [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#write).

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this requires a dependency called ghostscript. On Mac OSX, I used brew:

```
brew install gs
```

Now it works.